# Background color smaller than image in that div

Tags: html, css

I have a problem making background color smaller than the image in that div. Tried background-size property and searched the web. Using bootstrap with img-responsive class on that image. Here is the example of what I want to do.I must not make a new image with that background color.
Thank you for help.
[White logo is png image and blue the background color. Black is the background image of the body.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUmZN.jpg)

[The nav bar is done, but the logo with background needs to be same size as the navigation pills. Tried giving heigth the whole row but it dosent work.
This is how it supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrDmW.jpg)

Comment: <div class="col-sm-3 logo">
 <img src="img/logo.png" class="img-responsive">
</div>

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use a pseudo element to do that

```css
div {
  background: black;
}

span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
span::before {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 50px;
  background: lightblue;
}
span img {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>  
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYFJA.png">
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: It is working but know the image gets disorder while resizing window.

Comment: @MaxZix Made a minor update of my answer, where I added a span for the background color, it that helps ... else, as I suggested, post another

Answer (score 0):

You could create a DIV behind the other elements that would do the exactly thing that background-color does.
For example :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#background {
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    bottom:20px;
    right:20px;
    left:20px;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="background"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <div class="col-sm-3">
       <div class="background">
        <img src="img/logo.png" class="img-responsive">
 </div>
</div>                                                                                                                  .background {
 background-color:#19708A;
 height:50px;
 background-position:50px;
 position:relative;

}
.img-responsive{
 width:70%;
}     And now the background is smaller than image but i can not move it down to be in the middle. Cant post picture here.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<style>
    .logo{background-color:#000;}
    .img-responsive {position:relative;z-index:1;}
    .img-responsive:after {content:"",position:absolute; top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;background:blue;z-index:-1;}
</style>
<div class="col-sm-3 logo"> <img src="img/logo.png" class="img-responsive"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use svg and change color to image

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
   width="612px" height="502.174px" viewBox="0 65.326 612 502.174" enable-background="new 0 65.326 612 502.174"
   xml:space="preserve" class="logo">

<ellipse class="ground" cx="283.5" cy="487.5" rx="259" ry="80"/>
<path class="kiwi" d="M210.333,65.331C104.367,66.105-12.349,150.637,1.056,276.449c4.303,40.393,18.533,63.704,52.171,79.03
  c36.307,16.544,57.022,54.556,50.406,112.954c-9.935,4.88-17.405,11.031-19.132,20.015c7.531-0.17,14.943-0.312,22.59,4.341
  c20.333,12.375,31.296,27.363,42.979,51.72c1.714,3.572,8.192,2.849,8.312-3.078c0.17-8.467-1.856-17.454-5.226-26.933
  c-2.955-8.313,3.059-7.985,6.917-6.106c6.399,3.115,16.334,9.43,30.39,13.098c5.392,1.407,5.995-3.877,5.224-6.991
  c-1.864-7.522-11.009-10.862-24.519-19.229c-4.82-2.984-0.927-9.736,5.168-8.351l20.234,2.415c3.359,0.763,4.555-6.114,0.882-7.875
  c-14.198-6.804-28.897-10.098-53.864-7.799c-11.617-29.265-29.811-61.617-15.674-81.681c12.639-17.938,31.216-20.74,39.147,43.489
  c-5.002,3.107-11.215,5.031-11.332,13.024c7.201-2.845,11.207-1.399,14.791,0c17.912,6.998,35.462,21.826,52.982,37.309
  c3.739,3.303,8.413-1.718,6.991-6.034c-2.138-6.494-8.053-10.659-14.791-20.016c-3.239-4.495,5.03-7.045,10.886-6.876
  c13.849,0.396,22.886,8.268,35.177,11.218c4.483,1.076,9.741-1.964,6.917-6.917c-3.472-6.085-13.015-9.124-19.18-13.413
  c-4.357-3.029-3.025-7.132,2.697-6.602c3.905,0.361,8.478,2.271,13.908,1.767c9.946-0.925,7.717-7.169-0.883-9.566
  c-19.036-5.304-39.891-6.311-61.665-5.225c-43.837-8.358-31.554-84.887,0-90.363c29.571-5.132,62.966-13.339,99.928-32.156
  c32.668-5.429,64.835-12.446,92.939-33.85c48.106-14.469,111.903,16.113,204.241,149.695c3.926,5.681,15.819,9.94,9.524-6.351
  c-15.893-41.125-68.176-93.328-92.13-132.085c-24.581-39.774-14.34-61.243-39.957-91.247
  c-21.326-24.978-47.502-25.803-77.339-17.365c-23.461,6.634-39.234-7.117-52.98-31.273C318.42,87.525,265.838,64.927,210.333,65.331
  z M445.731,203.01c6.12,0,11.112,4.919,11.112,11.038c0,6.119-4.994,11.111-11.112,11.111s-11.038-4.994-11.038-11.111
  C434.693,207.929,439.613,203.01,445.731,203.01z"/>
<filter id="pictureFilter" >
  <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="15" />
</filter>
</svg>
```